# Set of values in dataframe columns

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, unique

all!

I have a dataframe. One column contains strings like this: 'Product1, Product2, foo, bar'.

I've splitted them by ',' and now I have a column containing lists of product names.

How can I get a set of unique product names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First flatten list of lists, then apply `set` and last convert to `list`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a':['Product1,Product1,foo,bar','Product1,foo,foo,bar']})

print (df)
                           a
0  Product1,Product1,foo,bar
1       Product1,foo,foo,bar

a=list(set([item for sublist in df['a'].str.split(',').values.tolist() for item in sublist]))
print (a)
['bar', 'foo', 'Product1']
```

If want unique values per rows:

```
df = df['a'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
print (df)

0    [bar, foo, Product1]
1    [bar, foo, Product1]
Name: a, dtype: object
```